Display Stock Tick data on react front end by calling websocket through a backend that calls the broker infrastructure
I am trying to create a watch list that shows realtime pricing.
The broker doesn't allow a connection to be created directly from the front end due to CORS.
Broker's websocket data comes to our node js backend.
What would be the best approach to get this tick data flowing from the broker to the front end with our nodeJS backend in the middle ? Any reference architecture would be really helpful. Thanks
